# Javascript/JSON/nodejs: Best way to randomly assign an array of values to an array of players without giving a player their own entered value

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json

So I have an array in which the following is stored

```
players[{nickname: data.player, id: socket.id, data: playerdata}]
```

playerdata is in itself an array

```
playerdata[]
```

in the first value of playerdata each player has entered a string. (playerindex is the index of the player that entered the string)

```
players[playerindex].data.push('STRING THE PLAYER ENTERED')
```

now i want to assign each name to a playerindex in the second value of the playerdata array:

```
players[playerindex].data.push(assignedplayerindex)
```

What is the best way to randomly assign each name to a playerindex checking that players won't get their own entered word and that each player is assigned a word.

I've tried this myself and got into situations where the last player couldn't get assigned a word, adjusted it and i feel that the direction I'm going in isn't efficient. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it, but I'm sure there are many ways to optimize this script:

```
//setup an array with all playerindex variables
        var playersnotassigned = [];
        rooms[data.roomindex].players.forEach(function(item,i){
          playersnotassigned.push(i);
        });


        //assign random name to each person, making sure that no name is send twice and you won't get your own name
        rooms[data.roomindex].players.forEach(function(item,i){
          do
          {
            //set the playerassigned to false;
            var playerassigned = false;
            //check if we are not dealing with the Last 2 players
            if (playersnotassigned.length != 2 || playersnotassigned.length != 1){
              //create a random indexnumer from 0 to players not assigned-1
              var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * playersnotassigned.length);
              //check if the random index isn't the same as the currentindex
              if (i!=playersnotassigned[randomnumber]){
                  //assign the data
                  rooms[data.roomindex].players[i].data.push(playersnotassigned[randomnumber]);
                  //remove that player from player assigned listen
                  playersnotassigned = playersnotassigned.filter(function(value){
                    return value!=playersnotassigned[randomnumber]
                  });
                  //set playerassigned to true;
                  playerassigned = true;
              }
            } else if (playersnotassigned.length == 2)
            {
              if (i == playersnotassigned[0]){
                rooms[data.roomindex].players[i].data.push(playersnotassigned[1]);
                rooms[data.roomindex].players[i+1].data.push(playersnotassigned[0]);
                playersnotassigned = [];
                playerassigned = true;
                console.log(playersnotassigned.length);

              } else if (i == playersnotassigned[1]){
                rooms[data.roomindex].players[i].data.push(playersnotassigned[0]);
                rooms[data.roomindex].players[i+1].data.push(playersnotassigned[1]);
                playersnotassigned = [];
                playerassigned = true;
                console.log(playersnotassigned.length);
              }

            } else if (playersnotassigned.length == 0) {
              playerassigned = true;
            }

          }
          while (playerassigned==false)
        });
```